# Stuggling to use function with async onload method with in a service in Angular - same function works perfect in component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, components

I have build a component in Angular that imports an excel file and convert it into an array and then displays the content on the excel file on the page as a table. This works perfectly if I build the fuction in the component as follows:

**data-import.compoent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataImporterService } from 'src/app/services/data-importer.service';
import * as excelhandler from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-import',
  templateUrl: './data-import.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-import.component.css'],
})
export class DataImportComponent {
  // Properties
  importedExcelData: any;

  constructor() {}

  importFile (event: any){
    const fileToUpload: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>event.target;
    if (fileToUpload.files.length !== 1)
      throw new Error('Can not upload multiple files');
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const binstring: string = e.target.result;   
      const workbook: excelhandler.WorkBook = excelhandler.read(binstring, {
        type: 'binary',
      });
      const worksheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet: excelhandler.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
      this.importedExcelData = excelhandler.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
        header: 1,
      });
   };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileToUpload.files[0])
  }
```

**data-import.component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="importFile($event)" multiple="false" />

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of importedExcelData">
      <td style="margin-left:5em" *ngFor="let cell of row">{{ cell }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that I am working at making my components as **"presentational only"** as possible - so the natural step would be to move this `importFile` function into a service that returns an observable subscibed to in the component as follows:

**data-importer.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import {} from 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import * as excelhandler from 'xlsx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataImporterService {
  // Properties
  importedExcelData: any

  // Functions
  importFile(event: any): Observable<any> {

    const fileToUpload: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>event.target;
    if (fileToUpload.files.length !== 1)
      throw new Error('Can not upload multiple files');
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      const binstring: string = event.target.result;
      const workbook: excelhandler.WorkBook = excelhandler.read(binstring, {
        type: 'binary',
      });
      const worksheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet: excelhandler.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
      this.importedExcelData = excelhandler.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
        header: 1,
      });
      
      fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileToUpload.files[0]);
    };
    return this.importedExcelData

  }
}
```

**revised data-import.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataImporterService } from 'src/app/services/data-importer.service';
import * as excelhandler from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-import',
  templateUrl: './data-import.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-import.component.css'],
})
export class DataImportComponent {
  // Properties
  importedExcelData: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataImporterService) {}

  importFile(event: any) {
    this.dataService
      .importFile(event)
      .subscribe(
        (importedExcelData: any) => (this.importedExcelData = importedExcelData)
      );
  }

}
```

The component template remains unchanged

The problem is that when try import excel files now with importFile funtion through a subscribed function I get the follow in my console

[image]

Having littered my source code with console logs every where what I can determine is that the service function is returning the `importedExcelData` before the asynchronous `fileReader.onload` has the opertunity to complete its work - therefore its returning an undefined observable, but after researching for several hours, I can't seem find a workable solution. As a last resort I am asking the StackOverFlow community for help. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to use an Observable to handle the async functions look fine. The only issue is, at the moment, no observable is created. You could create one using `new Observable` construct.

Try the following

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

importFile(event: any): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    const fileToUpload: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>event.target;
    if (fileToUpload.files.length !== 1)
      subscriber.error('Can not upload multiple files');  // <-- emit error

    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      const binstring: string = event.target.result;
      const workbook: excelhandler.WorkBook = excelhandler.read(binstring, {
        type: 'binary',
      });
      const worksheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet: excelhandler.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
      const importedExcelData = excelhandler.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
        header: 1,
      });
      subscriber.next(importedExcelData);  // <-- emit notification
      subscriber.complete();  // <-- complete and close the subscription
    };

    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileToUpload.files[0]);
  });
}
```

Since we are sending error notifications, you could pass an `error` callback in the subscription to capture them.

```js
importFile(event: any) {
  this.dataService.importFile(event).subscribe({
    next: (importedExcelData: any) => this.importedExcelData = importedExcelData,
    error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
  });
}
```

More info about Observables could be found [here](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)