# How to make a function wait for a async process to complete before commencing?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, observable

First of all - this question is linked to a previous question:

[Stuggling to use function with async onload method with in a service in Angular - same function works perfect in component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118594/stuggling-to-use-function-with-async-onload-method-with-in-a-service-in-angular)

So I have a service in Angular that writes an excel file to Firebase. The main function in the service calls three other sub-functions in the service as follows:

```
excelToFirebase(event: any) {
    console.log('1');
    this.covertExcelToArray(event);
    console.log('4');
    const objectList = this.covertMatrixToObject(this.importedExcelData);
    console.log('8');
    this.writeToFirebase(objectList);
    console.log('9');
  }
```

The three sub-fuctions are below:

```
  covertExcelToArray(event: any) {
    console.log('2');
    const fileToUpload: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>event.target;
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileToUpload.files[0]);
    console.log('2-1');

    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      console.log('2-2');
      const binstring: string = event.target.result;
      const workbook: excelhandler.WorkBook = excelhandler.read(binstring, {
        type: 'binary',
      });
      const worksheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet: excelhandler.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
      this.importedExcelData = excelhandler.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
        header: 1,
      });
    };
    console.log('3');
  }

  covertMatrixToObject(matrix: any[][]) {
    console.log('6');
    // Capture the header for Object keys
    let headList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
      headList.push(matrix[0][i]);
    }
    // Create objects and push to list to be returned
    let listOfResults: Object[] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      let resultOb: { [char: string]: string } = {};
      for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        let currentKey: string = headList[j];
        resultOb[currentKey] = matrix[i][j];
      }
      listOfResults.push(resultOb);
    }
    console.log('7');
    return listOfResults;
  }

  writeToFirebase(objectList: any[]) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < objectList.length; i++) {
        this.firestore
          .collection('Results')
          .add(objectList[i])
          .then(
            (res) => {},
            (err) => reject(err)
          );
      }
    });
  }
```

For referance `importedExcelData` is declared as `importedExcelData: any[][] = [];`

As you may see I littered my code with `console.logs` to see how the order in which my code was running... logical the console should log 1 to 8 in order (I missed 5 some reason), but the results are as follows:

[image]

I know I should rather use a step-into process to determine this, but can't seem to get it right on VSC (use to be easy on PyCharm). So what I can tell from this is that the `fileReader.onload` is not being allowed to complete before the entire `covertExcelToArray` function is completed and as a result when the `covertMatrixToObject` function is called it fails because at that point the matrix remains undefined.

My question is there a way I can get the `fileReader.onload`, which is an async sub-fuction  with in `covertExcelToArray` to complete before the enitre `covertExcelToArray` completes.

I know in my previous question the answer was to return an Observable from `covertExcelToArray` which was perfect when I used the response to populate a page from a component, but in this case I need to pass result to another function and subscribing won't work as the  `covertExcelToArray` and `covertMatrixToObject` fucntions would start in parallel.

Any help I can get would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fileReader.onload` is not an *asynchronous function*, so you cannot await it. It is instead an *event listener*. As such, the best and simplest way to figure out when it is completed is to use callbacks.

Maybe something like this?

```
covertExcelToArray(event: any, callback: () => void) {
    // your other code ...

    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      // ... your other code
      callback(); // this is new
    };
    console.log('3');
  }
```

Which you would then use like this

```
excelToFirebase(event: any) {
    console.log('1');
    this.covertExcelToArray(event, () => {
        console.log('4');
        const objectList = this.covertMatrixToObject(this.importedExcelData);
        console.log('8');
        this.writeToFirebase(objectList);
        console.log('9');
    });
  }
```

If you wanted to, you could always wrap your `fileReader.onload` event listener inside another function that returns a promise when the event is received. Then, you could `await` it or use `.then()`. If it would help, I could give you an example of this too.

**EDIT:**

I figured, why not provide you with an example of wrapping it in a promise too.

```
covertExcelToArray(event: any): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        // your other code ...

        fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
          // ... your other code

          resolve();
        };
        console.log('3');
    });
  }
```

If you wanted to convert `excelToFirebase` into an async function so that you can use `await`...

```
excelToFirebase(event: any): Promise<void> {
    console.log('1');
    await this.covertExcelToArray(event);
    console.log('4');
    const objectList = this.covertMatrixToObject(this.importedExcelData);
    console.log('8');
    this.writeToFirebase(objectList);
    console.log('9');
  }
```

If you can't do that, then you can use `.then()` instead

```
excelToFirebase(event: any) {
    console.log('1');
    this.covertExcelToArray(event).then(() => {
        console.log('4');
        const objectList = this.covertMatrixToObject(this.importedExcelData);
        console.log('8');
        this.writeToFirebase(objectList);
        console.log('9');
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you could give me an example of that as well - that would be great

Comment: @RubenFerreira Just did, let me know if it works

Comment: @RubenFerreira I just fixed some things in the async stuff. If you copied and pasted before i fixed them you probably would get a compile error

Comment: Hi Foxtrot - that solution worked perfectly, the only fix I needed to make was prefix ```excelToFirebase``` with ```async ``` as in ```async excelToFirebase(event: any): Promise<void> ```

Comment: @RubenFerreira Glad i could help